# How to make cluster on Folium with Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, folium

I have tried to make a Cluster on a Folium map. I have a dataframe as below.

[image]

The code for making the Cluster on Folium map is below

```
import os
import folium
import webbrowser
import shutil
import pandas as pd
from folium import plugins
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster

my_dir_path = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Sub_Folder"

results = defaultdict(list)
for file in Path(my_dir_path).iterdir():
    with open(file, "r") as file_open:
        results["Latitude"].append(file.name[0:9])
        results["Longitude"].append(file.name[10:19])
        results["Date"].append(file.name[23:25])
        results["Month"].append(file.name[20:22])
        results["Year"].append(file.name[26:30])
        results["Time"].append(file.name[31:36])
        results["Type"].append(file_open.read(1))
        
df_full = pd.DataFrame(results)

#Delete duplicate data
df = df_full.drop_duplicates()

df['Type'] = df['Type'].replace(
    to_replace=['0', '1', '2', '3'], 
    value=['Buffalo', 'Elephant', 'Rhino', 'Zebra'])
df

m = folium.Map(location=[15.170121, 99.159373], zoom_start=11)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(m)

for row in df.itertuples():
    folium.Marker(location=[row.Latitude,row.Longitude],popup=row.Type).add_to(marker_cluster)

m
```

I ran the code but map doesn't show anything. How do correct this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is probably that the cluster is set up first and the marker settings are made later. Therefore, the cluster setting was done after the loop process.

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster

m = folium.Map(location=[15.170121, 99.159373], zoom_start=12)
marker_cluster = MarkerCluster(
    name="clustered name",
).add_to(m)

for row in df.itertuples():
    #print(row)
    folium.Marker(location=[row.Latitude,row.Longitude],popup=row.Type).add_to(marker_cluster)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much. I'd like to ask you 1 question. How I can Identify "Type" and "Date", "Month", "Year", "Time" on folium popup. Now popup show only "Type". Please supporting me.

Comment: There is an [example](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/GeoJsonPopupAndTooltip.ipynb) on folium's github, you can display it in a popup by specifying the columns you need to display in the popup specification. `popup = GeoJsonPopup(...)`